Repair old keyboard where key combinations fail, and some keys fail at startup
I have a 14-year old USB Apple keyboard that I would like to refurbish, but I have no clue how to proceed. The tab key lost its rubber dome, so I replaced it with the dome from the Caps Lock key. Each key in the keyboard works individually, but the left Command key fails to work with "c" and "v", preventing the common use of copy-paste. Also, both Option keys fail at startup (even though they work when the computer is booted), preventing the boot into recovery mode.
Is it possible to diagnose and repair such a keyboard?
Update
I opened the keyboard following and here is a picture, showing clear signs of rust under the letter keys.

I assume that the metal plate is ground and conducts, so the board is not recoverable. Also, I found another key that does not conduct at all (the other ones I found did conduct, but not in combination with other keys).

Yes, that's a fair assessment and I updated the question :)

This sounds like bad connections inside the board. I don't know where to begin either, but beginning with careful disassembly and then checking the connections is a good place to start.

I feel like 'even' 14 years ago, these keyboards weren't really designed to be serviced. The top plate looks... lind of mangled

@JourneymanGeek Indeed, I used a heavy tool and a lot of force to take it apart.
